# Permanently redirect from example.com/foo.php to example.com/foo respectively from example.com/foo.php to example.com/bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule foo foo\.php [NC,L]
```

With this setup the page `/foo.php` is accessible under `example.com/foo` while `example.com/foo.php` is still valid. How to permanently redirect from `example.com/foo.php` to `example.com/foo`?

Alternatively, how to permanently redirect from `example.com/foo.php` to `example.com/bar`?

Comment: `foo.php -> foo` is possible but then `foo.php -> bar` won't be possible

Comment: @anubhava It should be *Alternatively* instead of *Additionally*. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a combination of an external redirection to enforce the clean URL and an internal rewrite to make the actual script available:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.php$ /$1 [QSA,R=301,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,NC,END]
```

This code generally handles such tasks without being limited to a specific file name like "foo.php".

---

What you ask in your last sentence of the question is not possible right away. You cannot somehow rewrite a requested URL to two separate resources. How should the rewrite engine know which resource it should chose? So the question with that details is: what is it you *really* want to know with that question?

Taking from your comments that with the last sentence in your question you actually want to ask how to *alternatively* rewrite to a specific target I would like to add this example demonstrating how to add an explicit exception performing such redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on

# explicit internal rewriting to a fixed target
RewriteRule ^/?foo$ /bar.php [QSA,END]

# external redirection to enforce "clean URLs"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.php$ /$1 [QSA,R=301,END]

# internal rewriting of "clean URLs"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,NC,END]
```

Comment: ++ but `QSA` is not required in both rules and even `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` may not be required

Comment: @anubhava That is correct, `QSA` is the default here. I personally prefer the old wisdom "explicit over implicit". But as said, just a personal choice. Whether the additional check is required depends on the exact situation and what the OP actually wants, I have the impression. But I certainly may be wrong in that.

Comment: It should be Alternatively instead of Additionally. I'm sorry!

Comment: Why is `QSA` implicit here?

Comment: Well... that simply is the behavior of a `RewriteRule` if the target does not specify a query string itself. I suggest you take a look into the documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Thank you! Could you add the code for the alternative case to your answer yet?

Comment: I added an example of such an explicit rewriting to a fixed target. Though I am a bit puzzled why you could not figure that our yourself from your own initial code...

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that I am doing it right and that I am not influencing other rules. Thank you!